# What is the best way to get page view per user in laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I already did this by a laravel package but its very slow in big data and creates memory out error.I want to know what is the best way to get page view per user.

Comment: Could you mention the package you used, so I could get a better idea of what you are looking for?

Comment: cyrildewit/laravel-page-view-counter. But its very slow that cause memory error in case of big data.@andriusRimkus

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy, auth the user => load data into page => render => done.
If u want to make your site faster use things like googles workbox https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/  then your performance should be good again.